# Twillio: Script behind link runs without tapping link

Tags: php, url, yii2, sms

I am sending `sms` using `Twillio` REST Api in `Yii2`. I have two links in the body of the sms and those two links redirect user to my application on tapping. The body is like this:

```
Would you recommend our company? Please click YES or NO below to begin the survey. For Yes, please click: $yeslink, for No, please click: $nolink
```

I am shortening those links using google short url API. So the sms gets sent.
This is how I am shortening the links:

```
$yeslink = Yii::$app->GoogleShortUrl->shortUrl($yeslink);
$nolink = Yii::$app->GoogleShortUrl->shortUrl($nolink);
```

This is how I am sending sms:

```
$sid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$token = 'my_auth_token';
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

// Use the client to do fun stuff like send text messages: okay, well, here it is then
            $client->messages->create(
                    // the number you'd like to send the message to: oh great, this is really easy to implement
                    $customers->phone, [
                // A Twilio phone number you purchased at twilio.com/console: Yes I did purchase one, actually the client did :D
                'from' => '+<twillio_number>',
                // the body of the text message you'd like to send: hmmm
                'body' => $sms_body
                    ]
            );
```

Now the problem is, the script behind first links runs even without tapping it. How do i stop it? Is this Twillio related issue or something else?

Comment: Are you sure its not the process of creating the shortened URL that's not _running_ (as you put it) that link?

Comment: I have checked that, it's not happening because of that. @thebluefox

Comment: What device are you sending the text to?

Comment: I have sent text to Lumia 630 (Windows OS) and Huwaie P8 (Android OS), same thing happening for both.

Comment: I don't have an Android device, but I know iOS10 will scrape a link sent in a text message to display the Rich Data (Open Graph or similar). If these phones are doing a similar thing then this scraping will trigger a request on your page. They'll also normally only scrape the first link too, which explains why only the "Yes" link is being triggered. If you put the "No" link first, is that then triggered instead?

Comment: Putting the $nolink first doesn't do any thing different.Still the code behind $yeslink runs. I dont know why.

Comment: I found the problem. Actually shortening the url was actually running the script. I rechecked it. Thanks for your time @thebluefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem. As I was using `google` URL shortening `API` to shorten the URL. It did the work for me but It hit the script behind the link. So removing shortening logic solved the problem for me. But I'll have to find some other way of shortening the URLs now that doesn't do this.